# Is it possible to call a popup without using onclick or href?

Tags: php, html

I have a button that updates the query, after which I want a popup to appear.
I have used it like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="details" value="Details"/>
 if(isset($_POST['details']))
 {
 // update function;

 call a popup;
 }
```

I don't want to use popup as

```
<button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Popup</button>`
```

Or

```
<a href="#openModal" id="btn">
```

I want it as isset(..) , Is it possible? If yes how should I call a simple popup having a message and 2 buttons? (I don't want to use alert, prompt, confirm boxes , It should be a popup).
Please help.

Comment: I don't really understand where do you want call a modal popup, it's in php code, after update instructions?

Comment: As II have mentioned in my post already, after clicking on my button details, I want to update my database and then get a popup

Comment: In your example there is PHP code so i assume you make POST call after pressing button and whole page reloads. If thats true then you can just put a div with your text and buttons and print it. (eg. `if (isset ($_POST['details'])){ echo '<div class='popup'>Here is popupext</div>}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are making the pop-up with java-script, you can do it like this :

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['details']))
     {
     // update function;

     echo '<script type="text/javascript">Call_PopUp(); </script>';
     }
?>
```

or even a popup with html (iFrame)

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['details']))
     {
     // update function;

     echo '<iframe> Pop-Up here </iframe>';
     }
?>
```

Comment: It gives the call popup as text, and same thing with iframes

Comment: What do you really want in the pop-up

Comment: In pop-up I have some text and 2 buttons like yes and no

Comment: you can put that in an iframe by using src

Answer (score 0):

You can echo javascript code with windows.open like this:

```
<?php 

 if(isset($_POST['details']))
     {
     // update function;

     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var url = 'http://www.google.com'; window.open(url,'win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=1076,height=768,directories=no,location=no'); </script>";

}
?>
```

The problem with popup windows is that are blocked by all modern browser, can you evaluate modal popup instead of popup windows.

Comment: It gives the whole thing inside javascript as a text

Comment: @LillyShk which is the goal of launching a pupup windows after update?

Comment: @LillyShk yes but what's the problem with solution proposed? after update, echo the javascript to lauch popup windows, you can remove all params to get more clear code, there is not way to open popup windows directly with php, you need to use javascript to archieve this.

Comment: I have tried with above solution but it is not working .

Comment: @LillyShk do you verified if the browser is not blocking popup?, I copy this code on php file and work fine, only need change the url www.google.com by your url and work well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71234/discussion-between-xzegga-and-lilly-shk).